# TakesScreenshot cannot be resolved to a type in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to take a screenshot of a webpage. 
I wrote the 2 line code but I am getting "TakesScreenshot cannot be resolved to a type". Please find below my code. look for File f1,scrFile or scrFile1. I tried all 3 still error persists.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Radio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://echoecho.com/htmlforms10.htm");

        File f1 = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(f1, "E:\\Pessoal\\QTPSelenium\\Screenshot1.jpg");

        File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("File Location\\File Name"),true);

        File scrFile1 = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
        FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile1, new File("c:\\tmp\\screenshot.png"));

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        List<WebElement> allRadios= driver.findElements(By.name("group1"));
        System.out.println("Total -->"+allRadios.size());

        System.out.println("Before");
        System.out.println(allRadios.get(0).getAttribute("checked"));
        System.out.println(allRadios.get(1).getAttribute("checked"));       
        System.out.println(allRadios.get(2).getAttribute("checked"));
        allRadios.get(0).click();
        System.out.println("After");
        System.out.println(allRadios.get(0).getAttribute("checked"));
        System.out.println(allRadios.get(1).getAttribute("checked"));       
        System.out.println(allRadios.get(2).getAttribute("checked"));



    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;`

Comment: Still i get the same error. "Screenshot cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: @MohammedSajjad I edited my answer, use your old code with `TakesScreenshot` and add `import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;`